# Input parameters when calling a script in E

Tags: r

I have an rscript that looks like this (its different but this is for reproducing purposes :)).

```
#createOutputFunction.R

createOutput <- function(parameter1, parameter2){

  x <- parameter1 + parameter2
  print(x)

 }
```

This works. But the thing is that I would like to call the parameters to execute the function. So basically want to be able to do:

```
source("createOutputFunction.R") and input the parameters directly
```

so that with only calling sourceOutputFunction i can get a different output, depending on the parameters I enter.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Comment: The source command only adds the function `createOutput` into the user environment. You can still execute the function by putting in the specified parameter 1 and parameter 2 into the createOutput function, e.g. `createOutput(parameter1= x, parameter2 = y)`

Comment: @AdamQuek I know but let say I want to run it in a cronjob / windows schedules job... How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# main.R file

source("createOutputFunction.R")
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

createOutput(args[1], args[2])

# end of main.R file
```

Now run Rscript with input arguments that is passed on to `main.R`.

```
Rscript main.R 1 2
```

This should print out `3`.